# What are the best ways to grind Wheat Slims?

Tags: cookie-clicker

I need to make more money on cookie clicker and I thought that I could grind Wheat Slims, I have a level 3 farm and I have unlocked Cornrice and Thumbcorn. Any suggestions?

Note: I will not use glitches or cheats, this is a clean run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As idle games go, the more you play, the more you gain. If you keep the game open, not only do you have the opportunity to collect Golden Cookies, you also collect your usual amount faster than if the game was closed.

If you get your farm up to level 9, you will be able to plant up to 36 Bakers Wheat at once, which will drastically increase your odds of obtaining Wheat Slims, as they only have a .1% chance of dropping when you harvest a mature Wheat.

As for the rest of your garden, I would recommend checking out the [Wiki](https://cookieclicker.fandom.com/wiki/Garden) for plant combinations for new seeds.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I use a different chart for the seeds and combinations.

Answer (score -5):

You could get a auto-clicker macro

Comment: As answers go, this one is extremely low quality.  It can be improved by trying to flesh out how this would solve the problem.  Something specific to the issue would also be helpful.

Comment: That is true, and I'm not using glitches as an awnser

Comment: Lsootgamer13 its not a glitch.

Comment: Ive never played cookie-clicker but for many online games using an auto-clicker or macros are against the rules (take Runescape for an example), so this does not help the OP as they specifically say they want a "clean run".

Comment: Ah, hat makes more sense now.